# Set ScrollView Content size just while VIew Loads

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, contentsize

I want to configure the `scrollView` just while the View loads in the screen.But the content size is not working as expected while using `AutoLayout`.If placed in `ViewDidAppear` it works as expected but i want my scrollview to configure on `ViewDidLoad` method

```
@IBOutlet weak var addressScrollView: UIScrollView!{
    didSet{

        self.addressScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        self.addressScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        self.addressScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    }
}

var billQuotes = ["This is bill","Bill Smokes","Bill drinks","But Still Codes"]
var viewFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   configureScrollView()
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.addressScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.addressScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(billQuotes.count+1), self.addressScrollView.frame.size.height)
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //if placed in view did appear it works as expected but i want it to
}
func configureScrollView(){

    for bill in billQuotes{

        var index = find(billQuotes,bill)
        viewFrame.size = self.addressScrollView.frame.size
        viewFrame.size.width = self.addressScrollView.frame.size.width - 20
        viewFrame.origin.x = ((self.addressScrollView.frame.size.width) * CGFloat(index!)) + 10
        let addressView = UIView()
        addressView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        addressView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        addressView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        addressView.frame = viewFrame
        addressView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.847, green: 0.847, blue: 0.843, alpha: 1.00)

        var billLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(32, 8, addressView.frame.size.width - 34, 30))
        billLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        billLabel.text = "\(bill)"
        billLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
        billLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.337, green: 0.341, blue: 0.345, alpha: 1.00)
        addressView.addSubview(billLabel)
        addressScrollView.addSubview(addressView)
    }

}
```

**UPDated:I want my scrollView to configure in viewDidLoad so that it sees instantly not after fraction of seconds after view Appears**

Comment: Why you are configuring scroll content size programatically? Is it specifically needed, else you can easily do it on storyboards itself with auto layouts.

Comment: i want this to be dynamic...so i have added views and adjusted content size programmatically

Comment: Not sure if this would work or not, try this                                       self.performSelector("configureScrollView", withObject: 0, afterDelay: 0.5) It would be more easy using Auto layouts instead doing programatically.

Comment: i have done this using autolayout..can you please say how could i acheived this

Comment: Set height constraint to the view which you want to show/hide dynamically. Create outlet of each height constraint and update its height constant dynamically as you required.                                                      self. addressViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0; //Hide view            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];                                                                         self. addressViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50;//Show view                   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];  But its seems you are creating some view inside configureScrollView function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the contentsize of the `UIScrollView` in `viewDidLoad` as per your views (`addressView`, `billLabel`) in the scrollview

```
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(<Calculate width>, <Calculate height>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override viewWillLayoutSubviews and put configureScrollView() in there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you call `configureScrollView()` in `viewDidLoad` its `layoutSubviews` has not yet been run, so the `UIScrollView` doesn't know it's own `frame` in relation to the `superview` yet. So when you configure it in `viewDidLoad` it will be correctly configured for a frame of the `view` which will then change (the `self.view.frame` is probably `600` in `width` and `height` here). In `viewDidAppear` the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has already been executed so that's is the reason why it works here since now the `superview` has its correct `frame`.

What you can do is force the `layoutSubviews` before you configure your `UIScrollView`. I don't really understand the logic behind which views needs to be forced so you'll have to play around a bit with it. But something along the lines:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.setNeedsLayout() // Not sure if this is needed
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // Not sure if this is needed

    self.addressScrollView.setNeedsLayout()
    self.addressScrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    configureScrollView()

    self.addressScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.addressScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(billQuotes.count+1), self.addressScrollView.frame.size.height)
}
```